# Java (Swing) listen to key events

Tags: java, swing, input, key, listener

I am trying to make an Auto Clicker but I am having issues with catching key events, so that users can easily stop the program. I have absolutely no idea what is wrong, `addKeyListener` is not working either. Can someone please help?

Here is my code:

`AutoClickerMain` Class

```java
package com.autoclicker;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class AutoClickerMain {
    public static boolean generate = true;
    public AutoClickerMain(){
        addKeyListener(new KeyInput());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Auto Clicker");
        frame.setSize(1086, 1200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("AutoClicker", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

         try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            while (true){
                Thread.sleep(500);
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            }
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }

}
```

`KeyInput` Class

```java
package com.autoclicker;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        AutoClickerMain.generate = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant write code using Java swing to catch all global(OS) keyboard events. You can only catch key press events if focus is on your JFrame. **EXAMPLE:**

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
  .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
      @Override
      public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Got key event!");
        return false;
      }
});
```

If you want to catch Global key events without focus on your application using java you will need JNI and advanced OS dependent code.

Answer (score 1):

> so that users can easily stop the program.

Create a `JMenu` with an `Exit` menu item. Then you can assign an "accelerator" to the menu item.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use Menus for more information and examples.

You can use the `ExitAction` found in [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) to create the `Exit` menu item.